# Format plain text values in columns using \t in php

Tags: php, html, formatting, pre

I have the following code in php, when i execute it:

```
<pre>
<?php
$input = '<xml>
<user>
    <name>sujit agarwal</name>
    <age>22</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
</user>
<user>
    <name>ajay rana</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
</user>
<user>
    <name>pratap singh</name>
    <age>27</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
</user>
<user>
    <name>asdfasdfasdfasdf</name>
    <age>30</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
</user>
</xml>';
$sx = simplexml_load_string($input);
foreach($sx as $val)
echo $val->name."\t".$val->gender."\t".$val->age."\n";
?>
</pre>
```

**THE OUTPUT IS**

```
sujit agarwal   male    22
ajay rana   male    25
pratap singh    male    27
asdfasdfasdfasdf    male    30
```

now, my problem is how to align all the gender values and age values in a column even if a name is longer than the rest. Hope i made my problem clear. **This is to be done within the PRE tags. because i will later save this to a TXT file**

**NEEDED FORMATTING**

```
sujit agarwal       male    22
ajay rana           male    25
pratap singh        male    27
asdfasdfasdfasdf    male    30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$input = '<xml>
<user>
    <name>sujit agarwal</name>
    <age>22</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
</user>
<user>
    <name>ajay rana</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
</user>
<user>
    <name>pratap singh</name>
    <age>27</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
</user>
<user>
    <name>asdfasdfasdfasdf</name>
    <age>30</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
</user>
</xml>';
$sx = simplexml_load_string($input);

$output='';
foreach($sx as $val){
    $values[] = $val->name;
    $values[] = $val->gender;
    $values[] = $val->age;
    $output.=vsprintf("%-30s %s\t %d",$values)."\n";
    $values='';
}

echo '<pre>';
echo $output;
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

outputs:

```
sujit agarwal                  male  22
ajay rana                      male  25
pratap singh                   male  27
asdfasdfasdfasdf               male  30
```

Comment: This answer doesn't clearly solve a generalized problem. If the `name` is more than 40 alphabets, then your program will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to knock this up quickly for a shell script, the method is fairly portable.

Just pass an array of elements, with the columns tab separated - and it will return a formatted string with the columns properly spaced.

```
function function formatCols($rows)
{
  $colwidth = array();
  $rowsParts = array();
  $results = null;
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cols = explode("\t", $row);
    $rowsParts[] = $cols;
    foreach ($cols as $id => $col)
      if (!isset($colwidth[$id]) || strlen($col) > $colwidth[$id])
        $colwidth[$id] = strlen($col);
  }
  $colFormat = null;
  for ($i=0; $i<count($colwidth); $i++)
    $colFormat .= '%-'.$colwidth[$i].'s ';
  $colFormat = trim($colFormat)."\n";
  foreach ($rowsParts as $row)
    $results .= vsprintf($colFormat, $row);
  return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too hard.

What you have to do is figure out how 'wide' each column is. And then figure out how many tabs you need to append to it.
So you will need to loop through all the rows twice. First to determine for each column what the widest value is and then to 'print' the data plus the right amount of tabs.

Or you could just use HTML tables which takes care of it for you but I can understand that it is not an option.

Comment: I mentioned why i need to use the `\t` in this case, because the output is to be stored in plain text files. I dont need html because there is nothing to display to a webpage by this script

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop twice: 1 to establish the max length of each individual field, and a second one to write it out with that much whitespace (for which I'd recommend something like `vsprintf('%45s %7s %-3d',$args);`, or whatever the values may be.

Comment: If you mean non-HTML, then yes, it's just your strings & spaces, nothing more, but a very simple one-liner test could've told you that.